# induction on injection function

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, induction

**Prove** $$ T:{N}^2\longrightarrow N $$
   **such that** $$ T(x,y)={2}^x {3}^y $$ is an one-to-one function

which method should i use on this proof?
Induction maybe?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No induction is needed; just check the definition of *one-to-one*. Suppose that $T(x,y)=T(u,v)$, and show that this implies that $x=u$ and $y=v$. If $T(x,y)=T(u,v)$, then $2^x3^y=2^u3^v$; now use the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: Apologies for the misplaced edit (which was supposed to be to *my* answer). Phone screens are *too* small to see some things...

Comment: @Bill: No problem; it led me to catch a typo.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

[Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

One could use uniqueness of prime factorization (fundamental theorem of arithmetic), but that is an awfully *big* sledghammer to crack this *little* chestnut. Suppose $\rm\:2^i3^j = 2^I 3^J\:$ with $\rm\:i\le I.\:$ Then $\rm\:3^j = 2^{I-i}3^J\:$ so $\rm\:I = i\:$ else LHS is odd, but RHS is even. Cancelling $\rm\:2^i = 2^I\:$ yields $\rm\:3^j = 3^J\:$ so $\rm\:j = J.$

**Remark** $\ $ In fact we can replace $2,3$ by any coprime integers $\rm\:a,b > 1\:$ (or, more generally, in any ring, any nonunit cancellable coprime elements). Hence the result essentially depends on cancellation  and *coprimality* (not  *uniqueness* of factorization).